# Write "a" before a percentage?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, percentages

Is this sentence ok or should I take out the a's?

"A true gentleman is a 25% noble, a 25% gentle, a 25% respectful and a 25%... dumb. "

Comment: Take out the articles. You're using 25% to quantify "respectful" etc. but you wouldn't say "A true gentleman is a respectful", so you wouldn't say "A true gentleman is 25% respectful" either.

Comment: The underlying rule is that only nominals take determiners.

Comment: you could say, however, "A true gentleman is a quarter noble, ..."

Comment: @Jon Hanna: did you mean to put another 'a' in your last sentence? I can't make sense of it as written. But apparently the OP did!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I did, but I accidentally wrote it correctly!

Answer (score 2):

"A true gentleman is 25% noble, 25% gentle, 25% respectful and 25%... dumb."

No article. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

The 'a's, or indefinite articles, are totally unnecessary:

"Genius is 1% inspiration and 99% perspiration."

Comment: That'a a great example. Makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: they are not merely "unnecessary", they are wrong.